# A way to directly speed download large file to server from a URL?

Tags: php, server, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to download a large file nearly 1-2GB of file from an URL to directly to my server. The URL is sent to me by my user.I referred to each similar links on stackoverflow and some other sites. But was only able to download maximum of 244MB.

I tried this code

```php
$urlB = $url;
        //remove the query string and get the file name
        if ($url = parse_url($url)) {
            $cleanUrl = $url['scheme'] . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
        }
        //get the pathinfo() of the url
        $cleanUrl = pathinfo($cleanUrl);
        //get the file name
        $name = $cleanUrl['basename'];
        //check if the directory exists and create a new directory if it does not
        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir);
        }
        //check if the file exists and prepend a timestamp to its name if it does
        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $dir . '/' . $name)) {
            $name = time() . "-" . $name;
        }

        //create a new file where its contents will be dumped
        $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $dir . '/' . $name, 'w+');

        //Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
        $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ", "%20", $urlB));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 240);
        //disable ssl cert verification to allow copying files from HTTPS NB: you can always fix your php 'curl.cainfo' setting so yo dont have to disable this
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        // write curl response to file
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        // get curl response
        $exec = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        if ($exec == true) {
            $returnData[0] = true;
        } else {
            $returnData[0] = false;
        }
        $returnData[1] = $dir;
        $returnData[2] = $url;
        $returnData[3] = $name;
        $returnData[4] = $dir . '/' . $name;
        return $returnData;
```

i also tried this

```php
 $destination_folder = $dir;
 $name = 'movie';
 $ext = 'mkv';

 $newfname = $destination_folder . $name . '.' . $ext;

$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
   $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

   if ($newf)
   while(!feof($file)) {
     fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ));
   }
 }

 if ($file) {
   fclose($file);
 }

 if ($newf) {
   fclose($newf);
 }

 return 'File saved as '. $newfname;
```

and also

```php
$chunksize = 1024 * (1024 * 1024); // 10 Megs

    /**
     * parse_url breaks a part a URL into it's parts, i.e. host, path,
     * query string, etc.
     */
     $infile = $url;
     $outfile = 'web/movie/';
    $parts = parse_url($infile);
    $i_handle = fsockopen($parts['host'], 80, $errstr, $errcode, 5);
    $o_handle = fopen($outfile, 'wb');

    if ($i_handle == false || $o_handle == false) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
        $parts['path'] .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    }

    /**
     * Send the request to the server for the file
     */
    $request = "GET {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n";
    $request .= "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($i_handle, $request);

    /**
     * Now read the headers from the remote server. We'll need
     * to get the content length.
     */
    $headers = array();
    while(!feof($i_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($i_handle);
        if ($line == "\r\n") break;
        $headers[] = $line;
    }

    /**
     * Look for the Content-Length header, and get the size
     * of the remote file.
     */
    $length = 0;
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
            $length = (int)str_replace('Content-Length: ', '', $header);
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start reading in the remote file, and writing it to the
     * local file one chunk at a time.
     */
    $cnt = 0;
    while(!feof($i_handle)) {
        $buf = '';
        $buf = fread($i_handle, $chunksize);
        $bytes = fwrite($o_handle, $buf);
        if ($bytes == false) {
            return false;
        }
        $cnt += $bytes;

        /**
         * We're done reading when we've reached the conent length
         */
        if ($cnt >= $length) break;
    }

    fclose($i_handle);
    fclose($o_handle);
    return $cnt;
```

Is there any better way to do it with PHP or Laravel or should I change to some different Language ? Also it would be better if I can push this task to background. I am new to handling server files.

Comment: **can someone help me with this**

Comment: 1. if using php curl try setting ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);``` 2. while using $i=fopen(..,"r"); $o=fopen(..,"w") try using ```stream_copy_to_stream($i, $o); ```

Comment: @ИгорьТыра no it doesn't help it downloads till nearly 200mb and then breaks

Comment: maybe the disk is full or there is some quota for user running the script. try in this script to create a file and fill it with 1-2Gb of random bytes. will it fail to ? and try to debug an error message (if it is some).